# Rails validates a field that isn't included in page

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a sample app that I created and I'm having trouble editing the fields. Whenever I try and update my fields, it's triggers my "validates :password_confirmation" in my user model even though I haven't included the password_confirmation field in the page.

Here are some of my codes:

This is my 'pages/services.html.erb' where I display the data

```
<h1>Shows all users</h1>

<% if current_user %>

<table border="1">
<% @column_names.each do |column_name| %>
    <% if column_name == "name" || column_name == "username" || column_name == "email"%>
        <td>
            <strong><%= column_name.capitalize %></strong>      
        </td>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<% @users.each do |user| %>


    <tr>
        <td><%= user.name%></td>
        <td><%= user.username%></td>
        <td><%= user.email%></td>
        <td><%= link_to "edit", edit_user_path(user)%></td>
        <td><%= link_to "delete", '#'%></td>            
    </tr>
<%end%> 
</table>

<% end %>
```

And here's my 'users/edit.html.erb'. I have a users model fyi.

## Edit

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_message' %>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_field :name%><br/>
        <%= f.label :name %><br/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.text_field :username %><br/>
        <%= f.label :username%><br/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.email_field :email%><br/>
        <%= f.label :email %><br/>
    </p>

    <p> <%= f.submit "Update" %></p>


<% end%>
```

and here's my UsersController code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "User Sign Up"    
  end

  def create

    @user = User.new(params[:user])


    if @user.save
      sign_in_check @user
      redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :success => "Welcome to the Bakeshop"}
    else
      @title = "User Sign Up" 
      render 'new'
    end  
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to pages_services_path, :notice => "Update Successful"
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end  
end
```

Can someone explain this phenomenon and suggest a fix?

**EDIT**

Added my user.rb file code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'digest/md5'

  attr_accessible :password_confirmation, :name, :email, :password, :username
  before_save :encrypt_password


  validates :name,  :presence => true,
                    :length => { :maximum => 25}

  validates :username,  :presence => true,
                        :length => { :maximum => 25},
                        :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}                    

  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}

  validates :password, :presence => true, 
            :confirmation => true,
            :length => {:within => 6..40}

  validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true

  def self.authenticate(username, password)
    user = User.find_by_username(username)

    if user && user.password == Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    self.password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password)
  end
end
```

Comment: can you add your `user.rb` file?

Comment: user.rb code has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be here:

```
  validates :password, :presence => true, 
            :confirmation => true,  #Confirm 1
            :length => {:within => 6..40}

  validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true  #Confirm 2
```

in the first `validates` block, the code that I've marked as `confirm 1` is basically doing the same thing as the code I've marked `confirm 2`.  The first block is all that you need as when there's a field with a password, this code will automatically confirm it.

The second bit is causing an error because this is not associated with the password field explicitly and so you're asking Rails to confirm the presence of the `:password_confirmation` attribute before a user is created or updated, which is unnecessary.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I see, I just thought I would like to validate the presence on my password_confirmation field. And you're right, by removing that validates method, my errors have been fixed. Thanks. But I still have no idea why it's validating that password_field :(

Answer (score 0):

Rails will validate against the validators of the class User, even though you are not using all the fields of that class.

If you don't want to use or validate all the fields of the class User in your view, you should use another view model class or simply remove the validation that you don't want to use (in this case password_confirmation).